# Determine cell separator

Tags: java, parsing, text-parsing, heuristics

As input I get an array of strings from the user. I need to split these lines so that they form a table, with equal number of cells per row. The cells should contain numbers. I want to determine the best guess for a cell separator character, and present this to the user as a default value, which he can then change if the guess was bad.

I assume it is one of the following: **tab**, **semicolon**, **space** or **comma**. Comma is critical, since this is also used as the decimal point in German and other cultures. The input may contain rows such as "1.0,2.0,3.0" or "1,0;2,0;3,0"

My primitive solution so far is this:

```
private char getSeparator(String[] rows) {
    String firstRow = rows[0];
    char[] possibleSeparators = new char[] {'\t',';',' ',','};
    char separator = possibleSeparators[1];
    for (int i=0;i<possibleSeparators.length;i++) {
        if (firstRow.indexOf(separator) >= 0) {
            separator = possibleSeparators[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return separator;
}
```

**Is there a better heuristic to get the best match for a cell seperator?**

Performance does not matter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over every row and search to see how many items the row could be split into using each of the separators.

Use the one which had rows split most frequently into the same amount of items for each row.

But honestly, this check, while clever and interesting, is likely unnecessary. The user knows their data. I'd pick a default and let them select a different one if needed. You could even persist their selection so they needn't select the same default over and over.

Comment: The most frequent split is dangerous, consider this row from a German table: "1,0;2,0;3,0".

Comment: My app is used by quite different people, and many do not understand why I am not able to make a correct guess for the separator.

Comment: Ah, I suggest selecting the separator resulting in the least varying number of split items then.

Comment: I go with this. It is quite similar to the solution Codo presented, I wish I could accept both.

Comment: Thanks @Christoph and its ok. We offered the same solution, and he got more upvotes so the rep was split more for him than myself. This is fair.

Answer (score 5):

I propose a more sophisticated algorithm:

- Read the first 10 rows
- For each row and each possible separator, count the number of occurrences
- Pick the separator that appears the same number of times in each row (and at least once)

Comment: I think this is quite close to the best heuristics for the task. It's possible to do optimize the algorithm based on the implementation, but basically, count the number of the occurrences for each separator, and then compute the variance of for each. The correct one should have little or no variance.

You may need to consider that the data may incorporate escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use reg Ex(regular expression) from java which will help you to achieve your goal.